# php - get specific variable from a foreach

Tags: php, variables, foreach

I have a functioning `foreach` that I want to expand on. It's simple:

```
<ul>
     <?
        $sql_find = "SELECT DISTINCT(column_chosen) as Sec FROM column_a WHERE column_chosen NOT LIKE  '' ";
            $get_var = mysqli_query($db, $sql_find);
            while ($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($find_var)){
            foreach($r as $newest_variable) {
            echo '                      
               <li><a href="#" class="first">'.$newest_variable. '</a></li>';} }?>              

        </ul>
```

Let's say its html output is this:

```
  <li><a href="#" class="drop">one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="drop">two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="drop">three</a></li>
```

I want to be able to get a specific variable ($newest_variable) and put it in `$_SESSION` or do other things, maybe alert it with javascript, etc, etc.

**Question:**
Is this possible with this structure? How could I get a specific variable `$newest_variable`?
For example, in the 2nd `<li>`, just get `two` and put into `$_SESSION['result']`

Any insight or direction is grealty appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by get specific variable and set? You want to grab it on click and set is in session?

Comment: Multiple things will be done with it. Getting it on click would work. I think my `foreach` needs modifying.

Comment: Are you just looking to get the second element of the foreach?

Comment: No, I want to be able to get any rendered variable. It has to be dynamic. Something like `$newArray[0]` or `$newArray[4]`, etc

Comment: Oh, that's simple.  One second, I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <ul id="itemList">
    <?
    $sql_find = "SELECT DISTINCT(column_chosen) as Sec FROM column_a WHERE column_chosen NOT LIKE  '' ";
    $get_var = mysqli_query($db, $sql_find);
    while ($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($find_var)){
        foreach($r as $newest_variable) {
    echo '                      
    <li><a href="#" class="first">'.$newest_variable. '</a></li>';} }?>              
</ul>
<script>
$('#itemList li').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    var text = $(this).text();
    alert('Index is: ' + index + ' and text is ' + text);
});
</script>
```

Heres small code with JQuery, you can pass those variables to php with ajax and set as session, as well execute other functions you want :)

Comment: This is just what I needed to do. I wasn't aware of jquery's `.text() method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make an array of all the elements from the foreach, it's pretty simple:

```
<ul>
<?
$sql_find = "SELECT DISTINCT(column_chosen) as Sec FROM column_a WHERE column_chosen NOT LIKE  '' ";
$get_var = mysqli_query($db, $sql_find);
while ($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($find_var)){
    foreach($r as $newest_variable) {
        $newArray[] = $newest_variable; //Makes an array of all elements of the foreach
        echo '
        <li><a href="#" class="first">'.$newest_variable. '</a></li>';
    }
}
?>              
</ul>
```

Now, the array `$newArray` will have all values of the foreach so that, for example, if you wanted the second element, you could use `$newArray[1]`.

Comment: so, given the right javascript, this could result in clicking on the 3rd `<li>` and having it alert "three", or clicking the 2nd would result in alerting "two"?

Comment: not looking for the js, just wanna know if this is the right direction i'm headed

Comment: Yes.  If you were to set the PHP array as a JavaScript array, that could be done.

Comment: ok. I'll probably accept this as the answer after I toy around with it. Thanks!